# iax2 check if register username and password is true

Tags: voip

i try to create simple softphone for iax2

and i send request true

`

```
    array = [0x80, 0x02, 0x20, 0xb3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x53,0x01, 0x01, 0x06, 0x0d, 0x06] + formatted_username_length_array + username + [0x07] + formatted_password_length_array + password + [0x13, 0x02, 0x00, 0x3c, 0x24,         0x12, 0x5a,0x20, 0x35, 0x2e, 0x36, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x20,0x76,0x32, 0x2e, 0x31,                 0x30, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x39,0x2e,0x39]
    
    self.socketSend(array)

    for x in range(1, 16):
        try:
            respo4 = self.sock.recv(1024)
            print(respo4)
        except:
            pass
```

`

and this is my response

`b'\x84j\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x01\x06\x04' b'\x84j\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x01\x06\x0e\x0e\x02\x00\x01\x06\x07ASTplay' b'\xba\x0e\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00S\x01\x02\x06\x04' b'\x83J\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x06\x1e6\x00' b'\xba\x0e\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00h\x01\x02\x06\x0f\x06\x07ASTplay\x1f\x04.\xf5\x80a\x13\x02\x00<\x12\x10\x02\x00\xc7@\xbc\xa1\xba\xa8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' b'\x83J\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x06\x1e6\x00' b'\x84j\x80\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x01\x06\x0e\x0e\x02\x00\x01\x06\x07ASTplay' b'\xba\x0e\x80\x02\x00\x00\x00h\x01\x02\x06\x0f\x06\x07ASTplay\x1f\x04.\xf5\x80a\x13\x02\x00<\x12\x10\x02\x00\xc7@\xbc\xa1\xba\xa8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' b'\x83J\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x06\x1e6\x00' b"\x84j\x00\x02\x00\x00'\x1d\x01\x01\x06\x0b" b'\x84j\x80\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x01\x06\x0e\x0e\x02\x00\x01\x06\x07ASTplay' b"\x84j\x80\x02\x00\x00'\x1d\x01\x01\x06\x0b" b'\xba\x0e\x80\x02\x00\x00\x00h\x01\x02\x06\x0f\x06\x07ASTplay\x1f\x04.\xf5\x80a\x13\x02\x00<\x12\x10\x02\x00\xc7@\xbc\xa1\xba\xa8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

so how i check if register is true or not